# Convert this string to datetime object

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime

I know that one can convert a string to a dateTime() object, but as far as I know the string needs to be in a particular form already e.g. "20121029".

I have a string that looks exactly like this:

> 2012-10-29T08:45:00.000

...Push in the right direction anyone?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is typical from [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) structure, `DateTime.parse("2012-10-29T08:45:00.000")`, should solve the problem.

To know more about Date and Time Fromat String see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97x6twsz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

With the `T`, that looks like the ISO date format (8601) commonly used by xml; consequently, `XmlConvert` exposes this very conveniently; try:

```
string s = "2012-10-29T08:45:00.000";
DateTime when = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(s);
```

Comment: Thats more ISO 8601. What is xml ISO ?

Comment: @Vash indeed you're right; [xml uses ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) - and as a result, `XmlConvert.ToDateTime` is a convenient wrapper to this exact functionality.

Comment: ,surely it can be used that way, but witout any XML context it might be confusing. That is why i will suggest using [DateTime.Parse(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), that also support that ISO.

Comment: @Vash true; my only concern there is that `DateTime.Parse` supports a lot **more** than that, making it a bit hard to be precise about input/result. `ParseExact`, I could get behind...

Comment: I think you you should point out that concern in your answer as it show new point of view on this topic. Thanks for that opinion.

Comment: @Vash - He shouldn't have to express his concern.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
DateTime.ParseExact Method
```

Eg.

```
 string dateString = "2012-10-29T08:45:00.000";
 CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
 string format = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff";
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Or

```
DateTime.Parse Method
```

[DateTime.Parse(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of datetime standard formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

And you can always write a custom format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Specifically, your format seems to match the "roundtrip" format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DateTime`'s `Parse` method...

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-29T08:45:00.000");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string strDt = "2012-10-29T08:45:00.000";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse (strDt);
string strDate = dt.ToString ("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will do all the work for you.

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Date dateObj = dateFormatter.parse("2012-10-29T08:45:00.000");
    System.out.println(dateObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this this might help

> using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using
>   System.ComponentModel; using System.Data; using System.Drawing; using
>   System.Text; using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> namespace DateTimeConvert {
>       public partial class Form1 : Form
>       {
>           public Form1()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();
>           }
>
> ```
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>       label1.Text= ConvDate_as_str(textBox1.Text);
>     }
>
>     public string ConvDate_as_str(string dateFormat)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             char[] ch = dateFormat.ToCharArray();
>             string[] sps = dateFormat.Split(' ');
>             string[] spd = sps[0].Split('.');
>             dateFormat = spd[0] + ":" + spd[1]+" "+sps[1];
>             DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>             dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFormat);
>             return dt.Hour.ToString("00") + dt.Minute.ToString("00");
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return "Enter Correct Format like <5.12 pm>";
>         }
>
>     }
>
>
>     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>        label2.Text = ConvDate_as_date(textBox2.Text);
>     }
>
>     public string ConvDate_as_date(string stringFormat)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             string hour = stringFormat.Substring(0, 2);
>             string min = stringFormat.Substring(2, 2);
>             DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>             dt = Convert.ToDateTime(hour+":"+min);
>             return String.Format("{0:t}", dt); ;
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return "Please Enter Correct format like <0559>";
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```